# Idiomatic way to handle side effect and return value in Scala functions

Tags: scala, monads, scala-cats

How would you construct a function in which you both want to do a side effect and return a value?
For example I would like the following function:

```
def futureFromHttpCall: Future[HttpResponse] = 
  doHttpCall.foreach(publishDomainEvent).returnOriginalFuture
```

(somehow I have a feeling that monads will come up so if that is the path Im somewhat familiar with cats if there is a solution for this problem there?)

Comment: You want to do some side effect as a result of the future returning and then return that same future?

Comment: Yes that is the case

Comment: And `publishDomainEvent` is a `Unit` returning method I assume?

Comment: Yes for example actorSystem.eventStream.publish(SessionCreated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Future should only complete when all of your domain events are pushed. They should be a `Future` as well. Then you can use `Future.sequence` to wait for all of them to complete before returning.

Your question is a little unclear but i assume doHttpCall is a list of some type.

```
def doHttpCall(): Future[Seq[X]] = ???

def publishDomainEvent(x:X): Future[Unit] = ???

def futureFromHttpCall(): Future[Seq[X]] = {

  val firstFuture = ???

  firstFuture.flatMap { xs =>
    val xxs: Seq[Future[Unit]]= xs.map(publishDomainEvent)
    Future.sequence(xxs).map { _ => re }
  }
}
```

All of this waiting can be pretty helpful when testing.

Comment: I like this, just wrap my domain event in a future

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing I can think of is instead of "hiding" the side effect inside the `Future[T]` returning method, expose it as a continuation on the future:

```
def futureFromHttpCall: Future[HttpResponse] = doHttpCall
```

And then you could either `onComplete` on it as a side effect:

```
futureFromHttpCall.onComplete {
    case Success(_) => publishDomainEvent
    case Failure(e) => // Stuff
}
```

Making the effect explicit. Or if you're inside an actor system, you can can `pipeTo` the `Future` to your `receive` method and handle success / failure there.